# SVG filter corruption

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using D3, I am creating a dial with a nice lighting effect using SVG with a filter. When displayed at the top of the webpage, everything looks great. When displayed lower down in the page, it usually (9 times out of 10) gets corrupted somehow during page load. I guess this is something to do with the dial being rendered and then moved, with the filter not catching up somehow, but I'm not sure. I hope someone can tell me why. I don't think I can reproduce this in a Fiddle but if I can I'll add a link. Here are the essential parts.

Just the circle without the filter.

[image: Just a circle]

The circle with filter applied and looking good.

[image: Circle + filter]

The circle with filter applied and corrupted. It looks like maybe the filter position is slightly down and right relative to the simple circle.

[image: Corrupted]

Filter code:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");
defs.append("path").attr({ id: "curve", d: "M20,20 A43,40 0 0,0 66,20" });
var f1 = defs.append("filter").attr({ id: "f1", x: "-10%", y: "-10%", width: "120%", height: "120%" });
f1.append("feGaussianBlur").attr({ "in": "SourceAlpha", stdDeviation: "4", result: "blur" });
f1.append("feOffset").attr({ "in": "blur", dx: 4, dy: 4, result: "offsetBlur" });
f1.append("feSpecularLighting").attr({ "in": "blur", surfaceScale: "5", specularConstant: ".75", specularExponent: "20", "lighting-color": "#eeeeee", result: "specOut" })
.append("fePointLight").attr({ x: "-5000", y: "-10000", z: "20000" });
f1.append("feComposite").attr({ "in": "specOut", in2: "SourceAlpha", operator: "in", result: "specOut" });
f1.append("feComposite").attr({ "in": "SourceGraphic", in2: "specOut", operator: "arithmetic", k1: "0", k2: "1", k3: "1", k4: "0", result: "litPaint" });
var merge = f1.append("feMerge");
merge.append("feMergeNode").attr({ "in": "offsetBlur" });
merge.append("feMergeNode").attr({ "in": "litPaint" });
```

Filter application:

```
svg.append("circle").attr({ cx: mid, cy: mid, r: radius, "class": "edge", filter: "url(#f1)" });
```

Comment: What triggers the 'corruption' of the filter?

Comment: What browsers are you having problems with? This should work.

Comment: Pablo, I'm not sure. It happens during page render. My best guess is that it's because the dial is rendered then moved down the page as other items are rendered above it.

Comment: Michael, the problem does not happen in IE 11 or Firefox 32. The top item on the page is rendered last for some unknown reason and this only happens in Chrome, so I suspect it is connected to the problem. All I can add is that there's multiple components on the page, each of which is created from an AngularJS directive and most of them generate SVG with D3. I don't know if any of this is relevant.

Comment: @Mark what version(s) of chrome have this problem? Please file a bugreport at http://crbug.com for this (and include a testcase/url showing the problem).